# How to get data from a URL in new lines using JSOUP?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm scrapping IMDB chart of 250 movies. I want to store each movie name in an array, but I don't know why it puts all the movie names into the first index, i.e Array[0].
Below is my code.

Can anyone please help me out. I've to complete another project and this is the main thing that is needed.
If you can direct me any website or tutorial I'll be very thankful to you.

```
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top").userAgent("Mozilla").get();

        int counterVariable = 0;
        for (Element el : doc.select(".lister-list")) {

            mString[counterVariable] = el.select(".titleColumn").text();

            totalNumberOfLines++;
            counterVariable++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry website couldn't be opened");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println(mString[0]);// It's putting all the names into this index
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have only one element matching selector `.lister-list`, so iterating over it does not make much sense. When you call `el.select(".titleColumn").text();` Jsoup concatenates text from all matching elements. This is why you get all results in one element. Instead you can try to select all `td` tags with class `tittleColumn` that are children of `tr` element that are child of `.lister-list`

```
for (Element el : doc.select(".lister-list > tr > td.titleColumn")) {
   mString[counterVariable] = el.text();
   totalNumberOfLines++;
   counterVariable++;
}
```

More about jsoup css selectors you can learn [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Comment: Luk. Do you know some websites where I can find some video tutorials on JSOUP? I searched on YouTube but they are just teaching scrapping IMDB list. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't know any video tutorials about Jsoup, but I think the text examples from their website are quite good.